# puma-dev link not working under Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, puma

I'm work on Linux and I develop a Ruby on Rails application.

I've set up the puma-dev seeing [this page](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) and they say, if you are working on Linux, please setup [dev-tld-resolver](https://github.com/puma/dev-tld-resolver).

I have completed both setups and I want to test if they work correctly.

I linked puma-dev to my Rails app and run it in the foreground with the `-sysbind` option. It runs, but if I type the URL (`myapp.dev`), it does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your question should include the relevant details to "repro" it. Linking to external tutorials means: as soon as those links break, your question (and potential answers) turn almost useless.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

The problem was Firefox. Firefox not support `.dev` domain so it couldn't connect to my application.

As I turn my app with Google Chrome, it executed correctly.